# How to change route State Params for current route using Router Service

Tags: angular, parameters, state, router

I have multiple routes in my Angular7 Application, all nested components. Lets say:

```
/pages/:appId/module/building/:buildingId/floors
```

And I would like to reload same route/route state from other place that that component (floors) using global Router Service but with different parameter value (appId) for example.

I've tried to navigate using Router:

```
this.router.navigate(['.',{appId:'123']);
```

I even tried to hardcode such path like

```
this.router.navigate(['/pages/:appId/module/building/:buildingId/floors',{appId:'123']);
```

However those attempts only produced malformed urls

So expected outcome is to be able to change existing route state params using global Router instance, OR navigate to same state using different state params

Comment: Angular 7.2 contains new property in NavigationExtras  this.router.navigate(['.'],{state:{appId:"123"}}) but my navigation fails with this settings

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29891